# Ignite cache's Get method timeout delay

Tags: .net, ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.7.6 and try to set the maximum timeout of cache's get method. I expect that after exceeding this timeout exception will be thrown.

But nothing helps me to set it: nor SocketTimeout, AckTimeout, NetworkTimeout in TcpDiscoverySpi, nor ClientFailureDetectionTimeout from IgniteConfiguration.

Currently exception fires after undefined delay - from 40 seconds to 150.

How I test: switch off the network and call Get method.

How to set it?

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is `getAsync(key).get(timeout)`.

We can't guarantee and operation to fail or succeed in a given duration, but you can wait on a future for a set timeout.

Comment: Ignite emits Disconnected event before throwing Disconnected exception on such Get requests. So after Disconnected event, I know that all requests will be interrupted and I must go into Reconnecting state and wait till Ignite reconnects. If I will limit request time by myself, this logic will be broken.

Comment: I guess you will have to implement logic to take account of both timeout and disconnect/reconnect.